# Git revert a public commit only in local repository

Tags: git, version-control, git-revert

Suppose there is a public commit "xxxx" that I *think* caused a bug and I want to experiment locally with reverting that commit.

If I understand correctly from the documentation on `git revert` ([1](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert), [2](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/undoing-changes)), it works out the changes required to revert the target commit xxxx, *and pushes them to the public repository automatically*. Is that correct? It's that last part I'm worried about.

I.e. will `git revert xxxx` revert xxxx in the public repository?

If so, is there a way to do this just in my local working folder so I can build a copy of HEAD with that commit reverted and experiment with it, without affecting other developers?

Do I need to use the `--no-commit` option: `git revert xxxx --no-commit`?

Or is there another way I should do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Contrary to what you apparently read or heard, `git revert` does *not* push anything to the remote repository.  It just adds one (or perhaps more) new commit to the HEAD of your branch which functionally undoes the commit or commits you pass a parameters.  If you had a commit `abcd1234` and you ran

```
git revert abcd1234
```

Then Git would add a new commit to your branch to undo this commit.

In general, stuff only goes from your local Git to the remote via a `git push`, so as long as you don't actually do this you should be in the clear.

If you're feeling super cautious, you could always create a new branch and test the bug fix on that using `git revert`.  Incidentally, many people who use repos like GitHub will configure critical branches such that it isn't even possible to push directly to them, as a safety precaution.

Answer (score 1):

No, it won’t push the revert commit to public repo automatically.

`git revert <commit>` will only create a new commit in your local repo, and git `revert <commit> --no-commit` change the working directory as what will be after executing `git revert <commit>` but not actually create a new commit, and you can use `git revert --abort` to cancel the operation.

We can illustrate by graphs:

Assume the public repo and your local repo are synced at first on `master` branch:

```
A---B---C---D   master, origin/master
```

- If you want to revert changes of commit `B` in your local repo. After executing `git revert <commit id for B>`, the commit history will be:

  ```
  A---B---C---D---B'   master
              |
         origin/master
  ```

  As you can see, there has create a new commit `B'` to revert the change for commit `B`, while `origin/master` still point to commit `D`. Unless you execute `git push`, then the public repo will be updated.
- If you execute `git revert <commit id for B> --no-commit`, it will change the working directory of the git repo, but both `master` and `origin/master` still point to commit `D`.

  ```
  A---B---C---D   master, origin/master
  ```

  If you want the working directory clean, you can use `git revert --abort`.